# Simple SQL query to select a max

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, join

I need a small help with a SQL query.

I have two tables: `tbltrans` and `tbltrans_temp`. I want to select the maximum of tbltrans_temp `max(tbltrans_temp.transid)`.

If `tbltrans_temp` is empty and it returns null, it should then take the max of `tbltrans.transid`.

If both tables are empty, it should just return 0.

I tried the following but didn't get the result expected.

```
select ifnull(ifnull(max(t1.transid), max(t2.transid)), 0)  
from tbltrans_temp t1 
left join tbltrans as t2
```

Comment: Is this SQLServer or SQLite?

Comment: @MarkBannister -- I would guess SQLite as SQL Server doesn't support `IFNULL`.  However, both should support `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works using `COALESCE`:

```
select coalesce(maxtemptrans, maxtrans, 0)
from (select max(transid) maxtemptrans from tbltrans_temp) t, 
    (select max(transid) maxtrans from tbltrans ) t2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89841/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select coalesce((select max(transid) from tbltrans_temp),
                (select max(transid) from tbltrans),
                0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close -- just remove the join:

```
select ifnull(ifnull(max(t1.transid), max(t2.transid)),0)  
from tbltrans_temp t1, tbltrans t2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2897f/1